# What to do with different encoding

Tags: python, pandas, merge, utf-8, ascii

I have a dataframe with encoding UTF-8 and a second dataframe with ascii.

I merge them with the following code:

```
merge1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(comment_csv, sep=';', header=None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1") for comment_csv in comment_csv])
```

Eventually the one with encoding=UTF-8 create the following weird token: ¶

Whats the best idea.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is not the same as UTF-8, even though the character set is a subset of Unicode. Use `UTF-8` as the encoding for both (as ASCII is a subset of UTF-8).

Comment: I got an error when i use UTF-8. Because not everything is UTF-8

Comment: Then you are going have to specify the proper encoding on a case-by-base basis, rather than assuming every file in `comment_csv` can use the same encoding.

Comment: How should i do that? Finally i need to merge them anyway. So I read one CSV with UTF-8 and another one I read with ASCII. But when I use concat would I not get the same problem?

Comment: No, because `read_csv` takes care of converting the byte streams into `str` objects which are no longer encoded.

Comment: The purpose of the encoding is to determine, e.g, if `b'\xc3\xb0'` is the single string `'ð'` (using UTF-8) or the two-character string `'Ã°'` (using ISO-8859).

Comment: Oh that sounds right. I will try it tomorrow, thanks! It creates more work, because the numbers of csv files are not always the same. But data quality is more important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is an encoding with specific rules that are easily violated by other encodings, while ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a Latin-1) can decode anything, although only correctly if the file is pure ASCII or actually Latin-1-encode.  So if you know that your files are only one or the other, parse with UTF-8 first and if it fails use Latin-1.

Make sure the encoding is *really* [`iso-8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and not [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  The latter is common on Windows and not exactly compatible with ISO-8859-1.  See the links for details.

Example data files:

**data\latin1.csv** (save in `iso-8859-1` encoding):

```
Col1,Col2
penguin,pingüino
```

**data\utf8.csv** (save in `utf8` encoding):

```
Col1,Col2
Hello,你好
```

**test.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

def filenames(root):
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(path,file)

def read_csv(filename):
    try:
        return pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='utf8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='latin1')

merge = pd.concat([read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames('data')])
print(merge)
```

Output:

```
      Col1      Col2
0  penguin  pingüino
0    Hello        你好
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!!